# Access the C lang nested structure which is present inside the union in Go using CGO

Tags: c, go, struct, stack, cgo

I have a set of C structures defined in header files as follows:

```
typedef struct E2SM_KPM_IndicationHeader {
    E2SM_KPM_IndicationHeader_PR present;
    union E2SM_KPM_IndicationHeader_u {
        E2SM_KPM_IndicationHeader_Format1_t indicationHeader_Format1;
    } choice;
} E2SM_KPM_IndicationHeader_t;

typedef struct E2SM_KPM_IndicationHeader_Format1 {
    struct GlobalKPMnode_ID *id_GlobalKPMnode_ID;
    struct NRCGI *nRCGI;
} E2SM_KPM_IndicationHeader_Format1_t;

typedef struct NRCGI {
    PLMN_Identity_t pLMN_Identity;
    NRCellIdentity_t nRCellIdentity;
} NRCGI_t;

typedef struct GlobalKPMnode_ID {
    GlobalKPMnode_ID_PR present;
    union GlobalKPMnode_ID_u {
        struct GlobalKPMnode_gNB_ID *gNB;
        struct GlobalKPMnode_en_gNB_ID *en_gNB;
    } choice;
} GlobalKPMnode_ID_t;

typedef struct GlobalKPMnode_gNB_ID {
    GlobalgNB_ID_t global_gNB_ID;
    GNB_CU_UP_ID_t *gNB_CU_UP_ID;
} GlobalKPMnode_gNB_ID_t;
```

I'm trying to access the gNB field within the GlobalKPMnode_gNB_ID structure using an instance of E2SM_KPM_IndicationHeader_Format1 in Go, utilizing cgo.
In Go, I can successfully access the fields up to nRCGI using the following code:

```
indicationHeader_Format1 := *(*C.struct_E2SM_KPM_IndicationHeader_Format1)(unsafe.Pointer(&decodedHdr.choice[0]))
nRCGI_pLMN_Identity := C.GoString((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(indicationHeader_Format1.nRCGI.pLMN_Identity.buf)))
(.pLMN_Identity.buf are nested fields).
```

However, when I attempt to access the gNB field using the code below:

```
gNB := *(*C.struct_GlobalKPMnode_gNB_ID)(unsafe.Pointer(&indicationHeader_Format1.id_GlobalKPMnode_ID.choice[0]))
```

I encounter the following issue:

> _Ctype_struct_GlobalKPMnode_gNB_ID is incomplete (or unallocatable); stack allocation disallowed

What is the correct way to access the gNB field within the GlobalKPMnode_gNB_ID structure starting from an instance of E2SM_KPM_IndicationHeader_Format1 in Go using cgo?